# Problem with refreshing canvas in windows form application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing

I'm trying to make sorting visualization algorithm in c# but I got a problem with  the canvas refreshing.

I tried to refresh the canvas every time I redraw but its not looks good. I'm sure there is another way to do it and I hope someone can help me.

In this picture you can see the black rectangles that I want to delete from the canvas

[image: pic]

This is my code :

```
    private void GenerateArrayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyCanvas.Refresh();
        Random random = new Random();
        int xPosition = 0 , yPosition = MyCanvas.Height/2; 
        const int k_RectangleWight = 2;

        for(int i = 0; i < k_SizeOfArray; i++)
        {
            int rectangleHeight = random.Next(MyCanvas.Height / 2);
            m_UnsortedArray[i] = new Rectangle(xPosition,yPosition, k_RectangleWight, rectangleHeight);
            xPosition += 5;
        }

        draw(m_UnsortedArray, Pens.Black);

    }

    private void draw(Rectangle[] i_ArrayToDraw, Pen i_PenColor)
    {
        var graphics = MyCanvas.CreateGraphics();
        graphics.DrawRectangles(i_PenColor, i_ArrayToDraw);
        graphics.Dispose();
    }

    private void SortingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bubbleSort();
        draw(m_UnsortedArray, Pens.Green);
    }

    private void bubbleSort()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < m_UnsortedArray.Length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < m_UnsortedArray.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if(m_UnsortedArray[j].Height > m_UnsortedArray[j + 1].Height)
                {
                    swap(ref m_UnsortedArray[j], ref m_UnsortedArray[j+1]);
                }
            }
            draw(m_UnsortedArray,Pens.Black);
        }
    }

    private void swap(ref Rectangle i_Rectangle1, ref Rectangle i_Rectangle2)
    {
        // Swap the position of the rectangle
        var location = i_Rectangle1.Location;
        i_Rectangle1.Location = i_Rectangle2.Location;
        i_Rectangle2.Location = location;

        // Swap the position of the current rectangle in the array
        var copyRect = i_Rectangle1;
        i_Rectangle1 = i_Rectangle2;
        i_Rectangle2 = copyRect;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawing canvas in question `MyCanvas` whether its a PictureBox or a Panel or the Form itself, provides specific events for the painting routines, particularly the `Paint` event in this context. The event has a `PaintEventArgs` which provides a **free** `Graphics` object to do your drawings. Meaning, you don't need to create extra `Graphics` objects like in your `draw` method. Now let's draw those rectangles.

Class level fields:

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//...

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const int k_RectangleWight = 2;
    private const int k_SizeOfArray = 100; //assign the right value.

    private Rectangle[] m_UnsortedArray;
    Random rand = new Random();
    private Pen MyPen;
```

Handle the `Paint` event of the `MyCanvas` control.

```cs
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //You can add normal event handler instead if you prefer so.
        MyCanvas.Paint += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (MyPen != null)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangles(MyPen, m_UnsortedArray);
        };
    }
```

In the `GenerateArrayButton_Click` event, create the rectangles, assign the drawing pen, and call the `Invalidate()` method of the drawing canvas.

```cs
    private void GenerateArrayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_UnsortedArray = new Rectangle[k_SizeOfArray];
        var xPosition = 0;
        var yPosition = MyCanvas.Height / 2;
        for(var i = 0; i < k_SizeOfArray; i++)
        {
            var rectangleHeight = rand.Next(MyCanvas.Height / 2);
            m_UnsortedArray[i] = new Rectangle(
                xPosition, 
                yPosition, 
                k_RectangleWight, 
                rectangleHeight);
            xPosition += 5;
        }
        MyPen = Pens.Black;
        MyCanvas.Invalidate();
    }
```

At this point, you will get something drawn like this:

[image: SOQ61443730A]

Now the second part. Your methods for swapping the rectangles:

```cs
    private async void bubbleSort()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_UnsortedArray.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m_UnsortedArray.Length - 1; j++)
                if (m_UnsortedArray[j].Height > m_UnsortedArray[j + 1].Height)
                    swap(ref m_UnsortedArray[j], ref m_UnsortedArray[j + 1]);
            await Task.Delay(30);
            MyCanvas.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void swap(ref Rectangle i_Rectangle1, ref Rectangle i_Rectangle2)
    {
        var location = i_Rectangle1.Location;
        i_Rectangle1.Location = i_Rectangle2.Location;
        i_Rectangle2.Location = location;

        var copyRect = i_Rectangle1;
        i_Rectangle1 = i_Rectangle2;
        i_Rectangle2 = copyRect;
    }
```

In the click event of the `SortingButton`, you just need to:

```cs
    private void SortingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyPen = Pens.Green;
        bubbleSort();
    }
}
```

... and you will get:

[image: SOQ61443730C]

Comment: Thank you for the clarification about the Paint method. i tried this code but i don't get the animation that i want to. i would like to see every swapping that i do and no just the end of the sort something like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPRA0W1kECg

Comment: @kobis Done. Just change the `bubbleSort()` method. Don't forget to `using System.Threading.Tasks;` and make the method `async`. Change the value of the `Delay` to make it faster or slower as you need. Good luck.